# Method for selecting interactions of interest

Tags: r, interaction, model, model-comparison

I have a set of 9 predictors from which I disregarded 3 in search of the best possible model (that with the highest $R^2$), so I have left with 6 independent variables. Now I want to find the best possible model including the interaction terms, but since I have 6 independent variables, I have 15 possible pair combinations of interactions.

Is there any R function or another way of selecting which of these interactions best contribute to my model (increasing the coefficient of determination) other than trying all of them and their different combinations out?

For example, if I have the predictors N, E, A, D, S and C I can have the paired combinations NE, NA, ND, NS, NC, EA, ED, ES, EC, AD, AS, AC, DS, DC, SC (15 in total).

a) is there any way to automatically test which of their interactions better contribute to the fit of the model?

b) Also, is there any way to check which combination of such interactions should be included in the model, again, for increasing its fitness?

Comment: which type of model/analysis you plan to work on?  Anova or SEM or multiple regression ?

Comment: As you add variables, you will automatically increase your R^2 - even if they are randomly generated. This is why model comparison methods typically incorporate some sort of penalty for adding additional parameters. There are better and worse automated ways to do this, but you are typically in danger of overfitting your model. You could look up cross-validation methods to evaluate your model's performance on a hold-out dataset.

Comment: It is a multiple regression. So are you saying I should rather not drop the 3 predictors I did drop form my model? I understand that logic but they appear to only make noise because the R-squared definitely is bigger without them on my model. Also neither of the beta coefficients for those 3 predictors seem significant (based on their p-value)

Comment: Only two-way interactions are of interest? What about 3 way or higher? Regardless and assuming you have created all of the possible combinations of two-way interactions, wouldn't it become a matter of employing some heuristic of relative variable importance to select 'which of these interactions best contribute to my model?' The best review of the rel importance literature that I know of is Ulrike Groemping's papers and R module, RELAIMPO. Her approach is computationally intensive and rigorous.

Comment: I have been thinking a lot about whteher I actually need to test all the possible regression models with the interactions, but you are right, I have no specific reason why only try 2-way interactions. One of my questions asks for whether a specific interaction between 2 predictors is antagonistic and by including that interaction in the mdoel I saw that my model did improve its R-squared value (not hugely but the overall R-squared is very low anyways). Also, this specific interaction makes sense in theory and it also involves the predictor with most significance in the whole model.

Comment: Thus, one could argue that thsi specific interaction is especially relevant to the model, whereas other might have a minimum impact on it or even be irrelevant. In that case would it be smart to only include this two-way interaction term based on the ground that it makes much sense (theoretically), and thus, use this as a "heuristic" of relative variable importance to select which of my interactiomns would maximize the model's fitness?

Comment: You are much better off using theory rather than just model fitting criteria. But @DJohnson is right your method for dropping three is not optimal so I would revert to the full model with all 9 unless theory says they were expected to be unimportant.